# Map values from one table to another table based on timestamp in postgresQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I have two tables. A transaction table that stores prices at specific dates (with precise timestamps). And a price-history table where we have one row for every day.
I now want to put the price from the transaction table in the price-history table where the timestamps match (same day). The below photo should help to clarify what I need. The price column in the price-history table is the needed result.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple join should work here:

```sql
SELECT t.date, ph.price
FROM Transactions t
INNER JOIN "price-history" ph
    ON ph.date = t.date::date
```

This assumes that the `price-history` table is like a calendar table, and has data for every date of interest.  If not, then we should modify the above to use a left join, and also we should select `COALESCE(ph.price, 0)` instead of just `ph.price`.

Comment: Good hint with the condition for the calendar-like table.

Answer (score 1):

To *update* the table, you would use:

```
update price_history ph
    set price = t.price
    from transactions t
    where t.date::date = ph.date;
```

Note:  If there are two transactions on the same date, an arbitrary one is used for the update.

If you need to *construct* the price history table, you might construct it first with `0` values and then update:

```
create table price_history (
    date date primary key,
    price numeric(10, 2)  -- or whatever
);

insert into price_history (date, price)
    select gs.dte, 0
    from generate_series('2021-01-01'::date, '2021-12-31'::date, interval '1 day') gs(dte);
```

And then update the values as above.